# YouTube Reporting Media Download Error

Tags: google-apis-explorer

The YouTube Reporting Media Download API explorer returns an error when trying to test a download.  I believe the issue is that the API requires alt=media, and the URL is being formed incorrectly.  Notice in the screenshot below that the URL contains a "?" before the second parameter.  Shouldn't this be a "&"?

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubereporting/v1/youtubereporting.media.download

[image]

Comment: There appears to be multiple issues with the API Explorer when trying to call media.dowload.  Based on the lack of response, I'm assuming this is just not used.  It would be great if it actually worked though.  Especially considering that the client library is also unsuccessful when calling media.download.  Now I am wondering where the problem lies; the API, the Explorer, the client library, or my implementation.

Comment: I was able to get the .net client library to successfully use media.download.  Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192489/how-to-download-youtube-report-using-media-download

Answer (score 0):

Just remove from the beginning of the URI "https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/" and also at the end remove "?alt=media..."
that's work for me